# Codeigniter : A lot of function in the same controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm newbie on codeigniter, I just learned to work with codeigniter it's been two week. 
I'm using in one controller more than 26 functions and each function load a diferent view. My question is when I load for exemple the function X in this controller (XXX.php), is that only the X function loaded? or all the controller (all the file XXX.php), I'm afraid if it makes website too long on loading?

Comment: that would be your least concern, loading a class containing 26 methods. Your concern should be in what the called action does that takes too much to execute.

Comment: So the call of methods is independent of the content of the class, if the method I use is not too long for execusion the page will not be too long to load even if there is 26functions in controller ?

Comment: As long as the method is not triggered (i.e: controller/trigger_method), it will not be taken into consideration (except when the controller class is instantiated by PHP, which you should not care about anyway). When it gets triggered, then it will eat time and memory, and that's where you should benchmark.

Comment: can u explain what does mean when it gets triggered ? :)

Comment: if you have 10 more minutes i can also explain how php works and also why the earth is round :) leaving the joke aside, when you access a url like `www.mysite.com/hello/world` then the controller called hello is instantiated, and the world method being part of that controller gets triggered. Is the same thing as `$obj = new Hello(); $obj->world();`

Comment: that was very nice your joke :D Thank you it's clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Controller will be parsed before it's run (as with all PHP), but it will only call the specific function.

To have a vague idea of what is going on you can use:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Inside one of your functions and then call it....it will display the profiler at the bottom of the page.

For more information on the profiler visit: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html

Hope this helps :)